# VueJS Router doesn't load the component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am using VueJS Router, but the router is not loading the components.

I have **About.vue and Contact.vue** just with  tag to test -  following is how it looks like :

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Contact page. Welcome baby!</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is **App.vue** with three router-links and router-view.

```js
<template>
   <div>
     <h1>Routing</h1>
     <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
     <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
     <router-link to="/contact">Contact</router-link>
     <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is **main.js** (the paths of importing files are correct)

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import {routers} from './router'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

let router = new VueRouter({mode: 'history', routers});

new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    router,
    components: {
      'app-home' : App
    }
});
```

This is the JS file for the router. **router.js** (paths are correct)

```js
import About from './About.vue'
import Contact from './Contact.vue'
import Home from './App.vue'

export const routers=[
    {
      path: '/' , component: Home
    },
    {
      path:'/about',component:About
    },
    {
      path:'/contact',component:Contact
    }
]
```

And, this is **index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>router</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="app">
       <app-home></app-home>
    </div>
  <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I load the page, the main page looks like the following :
[image: Loaded Main page]

and when I click the each nav, nothing is changed from the main page except URL.
URL becomes

http://localhost:8080/contact

http://localhost:8080/about

but not loading the component I imported.

If you need more information to give advice, feel free to ask more.
And if you have any clue of this issue, I appreciate if you share here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The object key `VueRouter` is expecting is called `routes`, you are passing it `routers`.

Try this...

```
let router = new VueRouter({mode: 'history', routes: routers});
```

---

Alternatively, rename your *"routers"* variables to *"routes"*. Eg

```
export const routes=[
```

and

```
import {routes} from './router'
// snip
let router = new VueRouter({mode: 'history', routes });
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to create a new Vue project (`vue create Project`) with `"Manually select features"`; then I had to mark `"Router"`.

Previously I've created a project with defaults and I've installed router separately (`npm install vue-router`) - but at the end the routing didn't load the components.

ps. I use:

- npm 6.14.6
- nodejs v12.18.3
- @vue/cli 4.5.4

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same symptoms as the OP but using netlify and gridsome (which uses vue.js. In my case it was a incorrectly tagged contact form that was the cause.